# Adding a field from another table to results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

If I have one table with companies in it, and another table with users in it, how do I take a field from the company table and apply it to all the user results?

Users have a `company_id` field tied to the company's id field.

`company` table:

```
id
name
```

`user` table:

```
id
company_id
first_name
```

---

How do I get a result with:

```
id   #   company_id   #   first_name   #   company
#####################################################
123  #   20           #   me           #   my company
124  #   20           #   otheruser    #   my company
```

I'm guessing it could be something like `SELECT * FROM usertable, companytable UNION ALL` but I'm not sure. Current implementation is looping with php to grab the company for each user, but this doesn't allow SQL "like searching" the company name!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply [`JOIN`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html) those tables on the specified column:

```
SELECT users.id, users.company_id, users.first_name, companies.name
FROM users INNER JOIN companies ON users.company_id = companies.id
```

Comment: Works as expected. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This is another method:

```
SELECT user.id, user.company_id, user.first_name, company.name 
FROM user, company 
WHERE user.company_id=company.id
```

Comment: Sorry i mis typed. tnx for correction. +1 vote too. :)

Comment: *Some old-style joins here!*